# unable to synchronize firebase in android studio

Tags: android, json, firebase

I have the `google-services.json` in the app folder but when trying to synchronize the gradle I have the following message

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  /home/dhmxl/AndroidStudioProjects/J-trock/app/src/debug/google-services.json
  /home/dhmxl/AndroidStudioProjects/J-trock/app/google-services.json
```

Comment: try like this **Build->clean project**  and  **Build->rebuild project**  .. if nothing happened restart the android studio like this. **File->invalid cache/restart**

Comment: check once have you placed correct google-services.json file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are placed the **google-services.json** file under the folder "**app**"